# Debian networking stopped working after I cloned VM image (virtualbox)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, debian, virtualization, vmware

After I cloned a VirtualBox VM image, either original nor cloned Debian 6 (squeeze) image have networking works anymore.

I've read A TON of articles online describing modifying the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and `/etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules` files but none of those "fixes" worked for me.

(Apparently this is a "feature" of UDEV that causes all kinds of problems if you are using Debian/Ubuntu in a virtualized environment for development and want to clone images because it changes your MAC address of your virtual NIC).

Can someone please described exactly what I need to do in order to have networking working again in my VM debian images. Thanks

***Note***: networking stopped in BOTH (all) debian virtual images now. Essentially, [1](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/660) how do I fix my MAC address since I don't even know what MAC address should now be used, [2] how do I prevent this from happening in the future when I clone VM images?

**UPDATE**:  My problem [was filed as a bug](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/660) with both VirtualBox and VMWare but both companies closed the tickets stating this is a "feature" of Debian.  Some people suggests ways to fix the problem but none have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following instructions: ["Network stops working after a CloneVDI / VM"](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=7749&highlight=udev)

It worked for me..

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing mac address of one of your machines so they are not identical.

More details:
Open virtualbox, settings, network, find network adapter and change mac adress.
Just change 1 sign so mac addresses are not the same.

Comment: If what you are describing can't be done with one (or both) of the two files listed above, then no.  Would you mind providing more details.

Comment: What MAC address should I use though?

Comment: The MAC address are NOT the same. That's the issue. Debian keeps automatically (dynamically) changing the virtual NIC MAC address